# How do you get Maya to communicate through the localhost IP?

Tags: maya, autodesk

What I have been researching with no luck, is how to get Autodesk Maya to communicate though the web on the localhost ip (preferably TCP). My goal is to control maya with a quick java application I wrote to manipulate curve selecting and such. If there is a way to do it in mel scripting, that would be awesome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maya includes the [`commandPort`](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2011help/CommandsPython/commandPort.html) command which will listen for incoming connections on a socket and run either mel or python scripts on the incoming data

examples:
http://fredrik.averpil.com/post/55507118045

[Opening a commandPort in standalone maya for unit testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28264406/opening-a-commandport-in-standalone-maya-for-unit-testing)

[use external python script to open maya and run another script inside maya](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27437733/use-external-python-script-to-open-maya-and-run-another-script-inside-maya/27450156#27450156)