# How to open a software using Socket in python

Tags: python, sockets, maya

I know that socket is used to communicate with server but can i use socket to communicate with applications ?

I have installed maya software in my Computer.I want to open that maya using Socket.Is it possible to open software using socket in python ?

Comment: If your "application" is a *server* which listens to a *socket* then yes. It's not really clear what you are trying to ask, or how much you understand of the terms you are using.

Answer (score 2):

Well before I give a Sample Code. I should warn you. This is not recommended. 
If you know how to open Maya software through Command Process then you can try something like this.

```
command = "C:\\ProgramFiles\\Maya\\Maya.exe" #random command
output = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
if output:
    output=str(output.stdout.read())
    print "Output:",output
    conn.sendall(output)

else:
    error=str(output.stderr.read())
    print "Error:",error
    conn.sendall(error)
```

Comment: thanks for response but i want to communicate with maya using socket

Comment: @python_fan Did you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30517443/how-do-you-get-maya-to-communicate-through-the-localhost-ip this question